# Inserting a changing table into another table. Tables values are the same when they should be different

Tags: insert, lua, lua-table

I am trying to make a table with tables inside of it.  The tables that go inside change slightly from their previous value.  But the end result is that the tables inside the main table are equal to each other and equal to its latest value.

```
local array = {}
local x 
local y

function test(a)
  if a==1 then
    x = {1,1}
    print("x returned")
    y = x
    for k,v in pairs(x) do print(k,v) end
    return x
  end

  if a>=1 then
    p=math.random(1,2)
    n=math.random(2,4)
    table.remove(y,p)
    table.insert(y,p,n)
    print("")
    print("y returned")
    for k,v in pairs(y) do print(k,v) end
    return y
  end

end


array[1] = test(1)
array[2] = test(2)
array[3] = test(3)

print("")
for k,v in pairs(array) do print(k,v) end
testtable=array[1]
print("")
for k,v in pairs(testtable) do print(k,v) end
```

Output:

```
x returned
1   1
2   1

y returned
1   1
2   3

y returned
1   1
2   4

1   table: 0x678300
2   table: 0x678300
3   table: 0x678300

1   1
2   4
```

The three tables inside `array` should be different from each other. What am I doing wrong?  Is there something about tables that I don't know?

Answer (score 2):

Tables are objects, which means a variable doesn't contain the value of a table. Instead, it holds a reference to a table. So in the function `test`, when you do:

```
y = x
```

Now `y` and `x` both reference to the same table. That's why the three tables inside `array` are the same.